# android twitter 4j integration get tweet entities

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

I am working on  twitter integration with android using Twiitter4j. I am trying to fetch Home timelines and its working fine. But when i am looking to get urls included in the tweets there is no functions. Is there a functon to get tweet entites like urls etc.

Here is the code

```
cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY)
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret(Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET)
            .setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken).setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(
                    accessSecret);

    try {
        TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        // gets Twitter instance with default credentials
        Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();
        User user = twitter.verifyCredentials();
        List<Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
        System.out.println("Showing @" + user.getScreenName() + "'s home timeline.");
        for (Status status : statuses) {

            System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText() + "--"+status.getURLs()+ "--"+status.getURLEntities());
        }
    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to get timeline: " + te.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

---

Works well with Sony's code and after that i have moved my code to async task and it shows some errors

Here is my edited code

```
        protected String doInBackground(Void... args) {
        String response = null;

        try {
            TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
            // gets Twitter instance with default credentials
            Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();
            User user = twitter.verifyCredentials();
            ResponseList<Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();


            System.out.println("Showing @" + user.getScreenName() + "'s home timeline.");
            for (Status status : statuses) {

                System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText() + "--"+status.getUser().getProfileImageURL());
                URLEntity[] uent = status.getURLEntities();
                if (uent != null) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < uent.length; k++) {
                        Log.i("URL Entity", "Dp Url " + uent[k].getDisplayURL()
                                + " URL " + uent[k].getURL() + " start "
                                + uent[k].getStart() + " end "
                                + uent[k].getEnd());
                    }
}
            }

        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to get timeline: " + te.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: twitter.getHomeTimeline(); shows error :- Type mismatch: cannot convert from ResponseList<Status> to ResponseList<AsyncTask.Status>

Comment: ok go to the line `ResponseList<Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline(); 
` and there keep cursor on Status and ther its taken status as AsysncTask class rather change it to twitter4j

Comment: like this `ResponseList<twitter4j.Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();`

Comment: great. It works. i haven't noticed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add one more line while creating object of `ConfigurationBuilder`

`cb.setIncludeEntitiesEnabled(true);`

(*Hint for the next code*)And you will get the Entities then,

```
ResponseList<Status> list = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
URLEntity[] uent = list.get(0).getURLEntities();
if (uent != null) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < uent.length; k++) {
                        Log.i("URL Entity", "Dp Url " + uent[k].getDisplayURL()
                                + " URL " + uent[k].getURL() + " start "
                                + uent[k].getStart() + " end "
                                + uent[k].getEnd());
                    }
}
```

Comment: thanks .But when i move my  code to async task doInBackground it shows some errors.

Comment: check if you are doing any UI operation in that or not?..or if it troubles you more..then ask as separate question.

Comment: can you help me to get uploaded images from twitter using twitter 4j android. Is there any function ?

Comment: i havent uploaded images to twitter..but there are many questions already in SO with good ansers for the same..and if still you getting some problem you can describe it and ask as question. :)