# How I can get all the text of a tweet that's been retweeted and extends 140 chars?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j, tweets

I have started learning `Twitter4j` API and have got all credentials and tokens from Twitter to use it. I am using twitter4j API version 2.2.5.

I am able to get my own `timeline` using a simple java program and print it on `console`. I am able to get all the tweets and retweets done by me using the code below.

```
List<Status> statuses;
statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline();
for (Status status1 : statuses){
   System.out.println(status1.getText());
}
```

The problem is I retweeted one tweet which consists of 140 characters, so after the retweet it becomes more than 140 characters. It is not printing the whole tweet in the console, instead it is printing `...` at the end.

```
 RT @xxxxxx: The ************************************ , but the pai.....
```

How I can get the whole tweet?

Comment: Aren't any characters after 140 discarded by twitter? If so, there's no way to get them. I may be wrong though.

Comment: No.I retweeted using their main website.I can see the whole tweet on my homepage.

Comment: Which API version are you using?

Comment: I am using twitter4j API .Version is 2.2.5.

Comment: Look at what's transmitted on the wire in response to your api calls, it might just be that this api can't tell you - if the server doesn't tell it

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834787/android-twitter-4j-integration-get-tweet-entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Twitter4J's Status Javadoc](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html), I would try this:

```
status1.getRetweetedStatus().getText()
```